# Should we have a separate beta site for any SO site?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

I was wondering if the new ideas for maybe SO could have a separate site like http://beta.stackoverflow.com/ and it copies everything from the main site, but for the changes have them there and users have the same flair. For example, if I post an answer on beta it is on the normal site as well and all the rep would be in sync.

Comment: You mean a site for letting users test new features, before they go live on the main site?

Comment: Yes. I that @Micheal Mrozek

Comment: What if a new feature is rep related?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You're saying _"...and all the rep would be sync"_.  What if a new feature changes the way rep is calculated?  What to do then?

Comment: Note that some changes are rolled out on Meta Stack Exchange and/or Meta Stack Overflow a few hours before other sites, just to make sure they don't break too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A valid idea, but one that would lead to many complications. For example when features are discussed on Meta. Is it on the Beta version? Or the real one? What if a change effects how data is posted, like an update in the markdown parser? Bugs would still affect both sites.

I actually like the way it is done now: The team tests things internally, and rolls out changes without much ado. The change will then meet either an uproar or general approval (or both).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better to have a Beta site that operates as a separate *site* - that is, users could claim the Association Bonus on it, and it would be treated as separate. So, if there is a change to how rep is calculated (as detunized speculated), it would affect solely that site. Also, the rules for posting questions and answers could be loosened to allow "test" questions, and people could in fact feel free to try out different things to either explore functionality or try to "break" the site!